# Crawler exceeds read capacity when reading from DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue

I am trying to export my DynamoDB table to S3 using AWS Glue. For glue jobs, I need to create a table in glue data catalog. For having my DynamoDB table listed at data catalog, I need to run a crawler (to determine table schema, I figured). When running the crawler, it starts to read a huge amount of data from DynamoDB which exceeds any read capacity units that I tried to provision.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way neither on the console, nor in the API to change any parameters for a given crawler when determining the schema.

I think if I could change the crawler to read the small amount of data or specify schema manually for DynamoDB tables would solve my problems. Do you have any ideas on how to do this?

Or, what other ways can you suggest to export DynamoDB tables to S3, if Glue is not the right tool for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for Amazon DataPipeline Service for this! There is a built in template that will require you to put in the S3 bucket where you want to export that table. All you need to do is fill in the params and then run the pipeline. You can schedule it to run as often as you need to or just once. See the link below for more details.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-template-exportddbtos3.html